# Is there is any way to create relation between two entites in Entity Framework, which doesn't have any relation in database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are the generated models:

```
public class DbObjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DbObject>
{
    public DbObjectMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => new { t.Type, CompanyName = t.CompanyName, Id = t.Id });

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        Property(t => t.Type)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.CompanyName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        this.Property(t => t.VersionList)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(80);

        this.Property(t => t.LockedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(132);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Object");
        this.Property(t => t.Timestamp).HasColumnName("timestamp");
        this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasColumnName("Company Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.Modified).HasColumnName("Modified");
        this.Property(t => t.Compiled).HasColumnName("Compiled");
        this.Property(t => t.BlobReference).HasColumnName("BLOB Reference");
        this.Property(t => t.BlobSize).HasColumnName("BLOB Size");
        this.Property(t => t.DbmTableNo).HasColumnName("DBM Table No_");
        this.Property(t => t.Date).HasColumnName("Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Time).HasColumnName("Time");
        this.Property(t => t.VersionList).HasColumnName("Version List");
        this.Property(t => t.Locked).HasColumnName("Locked");
        this.Property(t => t.LockedBy).HasColumnName("Locked By");
    }
}
```

and:

```
{
    public ObjectTrackingMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => new { ObjectType = t.ObjectType, Id = t.Id, ChangeType = t.ChangeType });

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        Property(t => t.ObjectType)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.ChangeType)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);



        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Object Tracking");
        Property(t => t.Timestamp).HasColumnName("timestamp");
        Property(t => t.ObjectType).HasColumnName("Object Type");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Object ID");
        Property(t => t.ChangeType).HasColumnName("Change Type");
        Property(t => t.ObjectTimestamp).HasColumnName("Object Timestamp");
    }
}
```

These two objects don't have any relation in database tables. But they could be joined by
`Object.Type = ObjectTracking.ObjectType` and `Object.ID = ObjectTracking.ObjectID` fields.

Is there any way to create correct mapping in EF using FluentAPI for these two entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is with Visual Studio - just open your EDMX file in graphic designer mode (double click it), activate Toolbox and Properties windows (in View menu on top), selct "Association" from Toolbox and drag-draw your relation from one table to another, than tweak it in the properties window.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. I've tried this way previously and didn't get success, because in this case I'm getting error: _Error 1 Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 136:No mapping specified for properties Object_Tracking.ObjectType, Object_Tracking.ObjectCompany_Name, Object_Tracking.ObjectID in Set Object_Tracking.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  Entity is type [demo_db_navModel.Object_Tracking]_

Comment: Ok, there is another way - in its core edmx file is XML, the graphic designer of VS is just for comfort. You can use an xml editor and just edit it manually. I'm not sure it will expose anything that the designer part doesn't, but since its the core, anything you can edit in a edmx you can edit there. The file is qute complex however. I sugest you find existing relation that most closely matches your desired result in form and try to copy all its parts, but with new entity and column names. Editing the generated code is a bad idea, since all *.designer.cs files get regenerated from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand Fluent API settings are meant to reflect on the database itself. Hence the lack of a setting for Minimum length on a string (which you can do with an annotation attribute). So your request for a setting through fluent API that does not get reflected in the database seems to contain a fatal contradiction.

In order to achieve what you are looking for, I suggest you do the "linking" yourself, possibly in repository layers that accesses these tables, the business logic or some other layer that sits on top of whatever data access layer you are using.

Hope it helps :)